# Class template specialization does not see base class members

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, template-specialization

While writing template specialized classes, I've got them not seeing anymore a base class member, like in the example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

template< typename T >
struct Base
{
    T m_data;
};

template< typename T >
struct A
{
    T data = 0;
};

template< typename T >
struct A< unique_ptr< T > > : Base< unique_ptr< T > >
{
    char to_char()
    {
//        m_data.reset(); // ERROR: m_data was not declared in this scope
        return 'X';
    }
};

template< typename T >
struct A< shared_ptr< T > > : Base< shared_ptr< T > >
{
    int to_int()
    {
//        m_data.reset(); // ERROR: m_data was not declared in this scope
        return 1000;
    }
};

template< typename T >
struct A< shared_ptr< unique_ptr< T > > > : Base< shared_ptr< unique_ptr< T > > >
{
    double to_double() const
    {
//        m_data.reset();  // ERROR: m_data was not declared in this scope
        return 3.14;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A< int > a_0;
    A< shared_ptr< int > > a_1;
    A< unique_ptr< int > > a_2;
    A< shared_ptr< unique_ptr< int > > > a_3;

    cout << a_0.data << endl;
    cout << a_1.to_int() << endl;
    cout << a_2.to_char() << endl;
    cout << a_3.to_double() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I could not give myself any reasonable explanation: the specialization works fine, but `Base::m_data` is not seen even if everything is defaulted to `public` by the `struct` keyword itself. It actually does not seem an access problem from the compiler error, but rather than the member variable itself is no there at all.

Comment: And you're convinced the specialization is relevant? What happens if you have an un-specialized template, with a dependent base-class, and refer to a base member in that?

Comment: `this->m_data.reset();` And there is a dupe I can't find at the moment

Comment: That may not be the dupe you mentioned, but it answers the question OK.

Comment: @Useless - It's not the one I had in mind. It's better! :)

Comment: @StoryTeller can you please explain to me why `this->m_data` works as a full answer?

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 - The duplicate is exactly for this

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 see the duplicates. There is an extensive answer to that.

Comment: See my first comment: this is nothing to do with specialization, it's just because the base class is a template. Once you know that, the duplicate gets you the rest of the way.

Comment: thanks, I was totally focusing on the specialization that I thought that something was wrong there.